# Assign a colour to a \lineload

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, tikz-styles, draw, points

I need to illustrate three different load situations. I need a load to act on a line in three different ways: equally, with peak on the uppermost part and with peak on the lowermost part. For this reason I am using the `structuralanalysis` package and the `\lineload` element. Now, I would like to assign to each `\lineload` a different colour. Does somebody know if that is possible by just adding a `draw=*color*` somewhere specific? Or if I should create a new command?

````
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \point {A}{0.5}{4.0};
  \point {B}{12.5}{4.5};

  \draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin] (-0.5,-0.5) grid (13.5,6.5);
  
% PLAIN   
  \draw (0.5,0.5) -- (0.5,5) -- (12.5,5.5) -- (12.5,0.5) -- (0.5,0.5); %Trapezoid
  
% BASAL FAILURE SURFACE  
  \draw (0.5,4.5) -- (12.5,5) -- (12.5,4.8) -- (0.5,4.3) -- (0.5,4.5); %bfs
  
% PLAIN  
  \filldraw[fill=brown, draw=black] (0.5,0.5) -- (0.5,5) -- (12.5,5.5) -- (12.5,0.5) -- (0.5,0.5); %trapezoid

% BASAL FAILURE SURFACE 
  \filldraw[fill=yellow, draw=black] (0.5,4.5) -- (12.5,5) -- (12.5,4.8) -- (0.5,4.3) -- (0.5,4.5); %bfs
  
% GAS RESERVOIR  
  
  \lineload{2}{A}{B}[-1][-1][.2]; %equal
  %\lineload{2}{A}{B}[-1][0][.2]; %toe
  %\lineload{2}{A}{B}[0][-1][.2]; %headwall
  
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:fig}
\end{figure}```
````

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Internally the `\lineload` macro uses the line style `normalLine` which is defined by the package. You can modify this style using `\tikzstyle` to use a different color. The line style is used in many other places as well, so you may want to reset it afterwards.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stanli}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \point {A}{0.5}{4.0};
  \point {B}{12.5}{4.5};

  \draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin] (-0.5,-0.5) grid (13.5,6.5);
  
% PLAIN   
  \draw (0.5,0.5) -- (0.5,5) -- (12.5,5.5) -- (12.5,0.5) -- (0.5,0.5); %Trapezoid
  
% BASAL FAILURE SURFACE  
  \draw (0.5,4.5) -- (12.5,5) -- (12.5,4.8) -- (0.5,4.3) -- (0.5,4.5); %bfs
  
% PLAIN  
  \filldraw[fill=brown, draw=black] (0.5,0.5) -- (0.5,5) -- (12.5,5.5) -- (12.5,0.5) -- (0.5,0.5); %trapezoid

% BASAL FAILURE SURFACE 
  \filldraw[fill=yellow, draw=black] (0.5,4.5) -- (12.5,5) -- (12.5,4.8) -- (0.5,4.3) -- (0.5,4.5); %bfs
  
% GAS RESERVOIR  
  
  \tikzstyle{normalLine}=[line width=\normalLineWidth,color=blue]
  \lineload{2}{A}{B}[-1][-1][.2]; %equal
  \tikzstyle{normalLine}=[line width=\normalLineWidth,color=red]
  \lineload{2}{A}{B}[-1][0][.2]; %toe
  \tikzstyle{normalLine}=[line width=\normalLineWidth,color=green]
  \lineload{2}{A}{B}[0][-1][.2]; %headwall
  % reset to black
  \tikzstyle{normalLine}=[line width=\normalLineWidth,color=black]
  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]